# Is some method called in the host app when today extension starts?

Tags: ios, flurry

I'm wondering if some method called in the host app when user opens app's today extension?

I use Flurry analytics framework to get statistics about my app usage and it's very important for me. But since I've added an app extension in the last update, the most users use my app only through extension. So now my statistics is horribly wrong because it shows only users that open host app.

I asked from Flurry support can I run analytics code in today extension and they answered no. So I want to start analytics code in my host app when today extension starts. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Your today extension is a separate app and not part of your main app. You could write some analytics to a shared resource and push it Flurry when the user decides to open de main app.

Comment: Ok, thx. But accuracy of statistics in this case will be awful I think :)